# What is List<Object> default size when we used JPARepository with SpringBoot?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

when we define a **List objects = new ArrayList();** then its default size is 10.

when we define a **List objects = new ArrayList(50);** then its initial size is 50.

But what if we used like : 
**List objects = xyzRepository.findByfield(value);**

For the above code:

1. which list is created by default and what was the default size?
2. What size of list it will be created if xyzRepository.findByfield(value)
   return 200 objects?

Comment: Why do you think it wont be 200?

Comment: As I know default size in Java is 10 and its increase its size around half of total size if required and so on. So for 200 its required to much operation so I want to know is there any mechanism used by hibernate

Comment: Looks like you are asking about `capacity` not a `size`. `size` and `capicity` are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate as you persistence provider then, when you go through the `getResultList` implementation, it returns this when there are no rows found (SessionImpl.class):

```
List results = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

Next step is it seems to guess the initial size:

```
        int guessedResultSize = this.guessResultSize(rowSelection);
        List combinedResults = new ArrayList(guessedResultSize);
```

After that, if something is found, the rows are added to `combinedResults` list which ends up having the either the initial  `guessedResultSize` or the size = number of rows found.